# Assign category by most values in groups

Tags: pandas

Dears,
I have a table where there is split between categories and sub-categories (i.e Brands and Sub-Brands) and Price Segmentation for every Sub-brand with number of product per each segment

```
BRAND | VARIANT (SUB-BRAND) |   PRICE SEGMENT   | SKU

DANISSIMO (DANONE) | VOZDUSHNIY | PREMIUM | 1

DANISSIMO (DANONE) | VOZDUSHNIY | MID | 4

DANISSIMO (DANONE) | VOZDUSHNIY | CHEAP | 2
```

My task is to create a table where for each combination of Brand-Subbrand there will be assigned only one Price Segment (PREMIUM/MID/CHEAP) assigned by the most numbers in the subbrand.

So in my example it should return table with a row
DANISSIMO (DANONE) | VOZDUSHNIY | MID|
as this Price Segment has the highest count among other segments for this Sub-brand

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Paste the actual Dataframe in the question itself, and preferably expected output.

Comment: So I've solved it by using idxmax() and apply()
price_segments=df.groupby(['BRAND', 'VARIANT (SUB-BRAND)']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.SKU.idxmax(),['PRICE SEGMENT','SKU']])